# Wedge Power symbol

Tags: symbols

I want the upper index to appear on slightly right and below the topmost part of
wedge symbol. 
But `\[ bigwedge^k V \]` gives me the `k` at the top. How do I do this?
I want this in the definition of exterior power of a vector space.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  It looks exactly like you describe. If you want to move it down further you can use `$\bigwedge^{\raisebox{-0.4ex}{\scriptsize $k$}} V$`.

Comment: This works properly in inline mode but when i use it inside \\[ \\] or \displaystyle , it does not work. How can i make it work in display mode.

Comment: I just use `\Lambda` for exterior powers, reserving `\bigwedge` for  the topological smash products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't like the default location in inline math, you can use `\raisebox{<length>}{}` to tweak the vertical position.
To get the same behavior in display math use `\nolimits`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Inline math mode it works as $\bigwedge^{\raisebox{-0.4ex}{\scriptsize $k$}} V$.

In display math:
\[
    \bigwedge\nolimits^k V
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simpler answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\extp}{\@ifnextchar^\@extp{\@extp^{\,}}}
\def\@extp^#1{\mathop{\bigwedge\nolimits^{\!#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
displaystyle: $\displaystyle\extp^k V \otimes \frac{M}{N} \quad \extp Y$

\bigskip
inline style: $\extp^k V \quad \extp Y$

\bigskip
scriptstyle: $X_{\extp^k V}$

\bigskip
scriptscriptstyle: $X_{X_{\extp^k V}}$
\end{document}
```

With `amsmath` the `cmex` font scales properly in subscripts and superscripts.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that qualifies as "simpler," but it's definitely more elegant. My one criticism (I can't really call it a "complaint" since I'm not the OP) is that in display style, the `\extp` symbol is still sized like a large operator. My own instincts (which may be mistaken) are that it should behave more like, e.g., `\operatorname{Sym}` (for symmetric product). In particular, not only the sub/superscript placement but also the character size in display style should imitate the inline version.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is really that `\bigwedge` is apparently designed to be used as an abbreviation for "wedge a bunch of things together," much like the `\sum` and `\prod` symbols. An exterior power is a completely different animal in terms of spacing.  While I don't really know what I'm doing here, I've made an attempt to create a macro `\Exterior` that gives a command with spacing and appearance appropriate for the exterior product:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Exterior}{\mathchoice{{\textstyle\bigwedge}}%
    {{\bigwedge}}%
    {{\textstyle\wedge}}%
    {{\scriptstyle\wedge}}}

\begin{document}
displaystyle: 
\[
\Exterior^k V \otimes \frac{M}{N}
\]

inline style: $\Exterior^k V$

\bigskip
scriptstyle: $X_{\Exterior^k V}$

\bigskip
scriptscriptstyle: $X_{X_{\Exterior^k V}}$
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

As you can see, it's not perfect, but I think it's closer to what we want for an exterior power. Perhaps someone more knowledgable can tweak the macro or rewrite it completely to produce a better result and/or make the code less of a hack.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this solution, I think it looks similar to what is used in, e.g., Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry

```
\newcommand{\largewedge}{\mbox{\Large $\wedge$}}
```

Comment: This does not scale with subscripts.

Answer (score 1):

[Andrew Swann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15925/andrew-swann) suggested in the comments to use `\Lambda` as an alternative to variations of `\wedge` or `\bigwedge`. This is what I currently do.

There are some shenanigans with `fontspec` and `amsmath`, but they can be [resolved](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477662/fontspec-breaks-capital-greek-letters-in-declaremathoperator) by using the unicode glyph `Λ` instead of `\Lambda`.

To obtain a style more similar to `\wedge`, use `\mathsf{Λ}` to use the the sans serif font.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Ext}{Λ}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Extalt}{\mathsf{Λ}}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \Ext^k V \\
    \Extalt^k V
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]