# fontspec breaks capital greek letters in DeclareMathOperator

Tags: math-mode, xetex, amsmath, fontspec, greek

Using `fontspec` together with `amsmath` breaks the use of capital greek letters in `\DeclareMathOperator`. Instead, the greek letter just is omitted.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\exterior}{\Lambda}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \exterior^k V \\
    \Lambda^k V
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: Two lines, first is the broken output, second is the expected output]

Removing `\usepackage{fontspec}` makes the Lambda appear.

Funnily enough, if one also adds `unicode-math` in the mix, i.e.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

it works. But `unicode-math` recommends to load it *after* `amsmath`, so it can override commands. Though this breaks it again, which is really confusing to me.

Is there a sensible way to use `fontspec` and `amsmath` together? Did I miss something?

Comment: Alternatively, you could typeset the operator using a properly changed variant of `\wedge` as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61637/wedge-power-symbol). (I guess that the convention of using `\Lambda` for exterior product space powers is due to laziness, not semactics... using `\wedge` seems more consistent to me.)

Comment: Yeah I actually came from this. Though mostly the symbol is too big for my taste (e.g. `\bigwedge`), or does not scale in subscripts (e.g. the solution using `mbox`). I also do not understand the more involved solutions, and am not particularly keen to add those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\DeclareMathOperator uses internally the operator font, and this is changed by fontspec. Why the new font does have a Lambda, it doesn't have it in the same glyph slot.

You could either load fontspec with the `[no-math]` option, or use the real glyph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\DeclareMathOperator{\exterior}{Λ}
\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
    \exterior^k V\\
    \Lambda^k V
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why the glyph slot is changed? That seems not very reasonable...

Comment: unicode engines and unicode fonts do change slots. You can't expect that a Lambda is at the same place in a OT1 legacy font than in unicode font.

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator{\exterior}{^^^^039b}` also works, and might or might not be easier to edit. It definitely makes it clearer which Unicode character is being used.

Comment: @Davislor Can you explain this? I also don't quite understand, *why* I can use `\Lambda` in my math, but not in `\DeclareMathOperator`. Apparently, `fontspec` also defines `\Lambda`, but `DeclareMathOperator` can not use this?

Comment: @Davislor that is nonsense.  \DeclareMathOperator uses internally `\operator@font` to print the operator, and `operator@font` is simply differently defined with and without fontspec.

Comment: @red_trumpet If you load `fontspec` the package willl load a Unicode font as your `\operator@font`, but try to still use legacy fonts in math mode. You can bypass the inconsistent definition of `\Lambda` by just telling it what Unicode character you want. The default text font (Latin Modern Roman) contains Greek letters, so it works.

Comment: @red_trumpet Contrary to what I erroneously posted, the second argument to `\DeclareMathOperator` is in math mode, but you can use a different math-mode command to get an upright Lambda. In particular, `unicode-math` defines both `\upLambda` and `\mupLambda`, which work.

Comment: @red_trumpet If you’re stuck using legacy fonts, you might try `\Uplambda` from `upgreek` as a workaround.

Comment: @Davislor No, the solution here works for me. I just don't understand what's going on under the hood. For example, I cannot use `$Λ$`, this will show nothing, but in `DeclareMathOperator` it works.  Do you know of any resources, where I could read up about stuff like this?

Comment: @red_trumpet It’s a little complicated to go into in the comments. Traditionally, `\Lambda` came from a special math-letter font in the legacy OML encoding. Then, `amsmath` operators set the font to `\operator@font` and are really intended to typeset text like `\sin` or `\log`. If you load `fontspec`, it tries to enable modern fonts in text mode and still support legacy math fonts that contain `Lambda`. One thing it does is change `\operator@font` to the text font. But it does this in such a way that `\Lambda` doesn’t work. It ends up trying to load the wrong codepoint.

Comment: @red_trumpet The solution is to use a different command to either load the Unicode character Λ from the operator font (the default, Latin Modern Roman, has it), or use a different math-mode command to get a Lambda. For example, `\mathnormal\Lambda` overrides the operator font and works (although this is slanted by default), `\upLambda` from `unicode-math`, `\Uplambda`, `\Lambdaup`, etc. from various legacy packages.

Comment: @red_trumpet Another alternative is not to use `\DeclareMathOperator` at all. You can just define it as `\mathop{\Lambda}` to get operator-like spacing.

Comment: @Davislor the upright lambda is not from OML but OT1. Try `\usefont{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}\char3`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Right, it’s the slanted `\mathnormal\Lambda` that comes from OML. As you say, character `"03` of Unicode is a non-printing character, so attempting to display it doesn’t work.. It’s also not in T1, as you know.

Answer (score 7):

The definition of `\Lambda` is `\mathchar"7003`, which means that when `\operator@font` is in effect, the glyph from slot 3 in that font is used, which doesn't exist.

You can avoid it with a trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\opgreek}[1]{\begingroup\mathgroup-1 #1\endgroup}

\DeclareMathOperator{\exterior}{\opgreek{\Lambda}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \exterior^k V \\
    \Lambda^k V
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise

```
\newcommand{\exterior}{\mathop{\kern0pt\Lambda}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Why That Happened

There are two great answers, but since you asked me to give you more information about *why* this happens, I’d like to oblige.  And I especially want to thank Ulrike Fischer for correcting my mistakes and teaching me something about LaTeX.

To see what’s going on, let’s extend your example a bit:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\exterior}{\lambda\Lambda\phi\Phi\omega\Omega}

\begin{document}
\(
    \exterior^k V
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems that all the Greek capital letters fail to display, but the lowercase ones show up fine.  Why is this?

As Egreg said, “The definition of `\Lambda` is `\mathchar"7003`, which means that when `\operator@font` is in effect, the glyph from slot 3 in that font is used, which doesn't exist.”  How does that work?

If you check [The LaTeX Font Encoding Guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf#subsection.A.1), you’ll see that character slot 3 of the OT1 encoding is Λ, and that the first eleven slots are the upright capital Greek letters that don’t look the same as a Latin letter.  (The rest don’t exist in classic LaTeX; there is no `\Alpha` macro in the kernel and you just use the glyph A.  In the days of 7-bit encodings, DEK didn’t think that was a good use of one of the precious 128 slots.)

In theory, every LaTeX text encoding has to support a minimal set of characters in the same slots as ASCII.  In practice, some (such as LGR) don’t, but all font packages will avoid breaking commands such as `\sin`, `\lim` and `\log`.  So, even if you change the text font encoding to something like T1, `\DeclareMathOperator` will still try to load `\Lambda` from an OT1 math alphabet.  As you’ve seen, though, some font packages *will* break your example, since that’s a non-traditional use of the command.

What does `fontspec` do?  It changes the text font to a Unicode-encoded font.  If you check the Unicode code tables, the Greek letters from OT1 all map to non-graphing control characters in ASCII and Unicode.  This is also why you will sometimes see an old PDF misspell “efficient flow” as “e cient ow.”  The classic OT1 encoding mapped ligatures such as `ff`, `fi`, `fl` and `ffi` to slots with no glyph in ASCII too.

What about the lowercase Greek letters, which did work?  Again, checking the encoding tables, they aren’t in OT1, but a different font encoding, OML.  Changing the operator font doesn’t mess that up.

So, how to fix this?

### Switch Entirely to Unicode

This is always my first option if I can.  The `unicode-math` package does not fix `\Lambda` in this context, but it does provide math-mode commands `\upLambda` and `\mupLambda`, and the alphabet `\symup\Lambda`.  This has the advantage of working even if your text font does not contain Greek letters.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareMathOperator{\exterior}{\mupLambda}

\begin{document}
\(
    \operatorname{Cl} \exterior^k V
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample]

Ulrike Fischer’s answer does this by using the literal glyph Λ.  `\DeclareMathOperator{\exterior}{^^^^039b}` is equivalent, and `\char"039B` or `\symbol{"039B}` would also work.  These load the glyph Λ (U+039B) from the Unicode-encoded operator font.  By default, this is Latin Modern Roman, which has it.

### Use a Simpler Command

If what you want is an upright Λ symbol with the spacing of an operator, you don’t need to change the fonts around.  And then `fontspec` won’t break it.  A simplification of an idea from Egreg:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand\exterior{\mathop{\Lambda}}

\begin{document}
\(
    \operatorname{Cl} \exterior^k V
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample]

### Use a Different Λ

Anything from a different math alphabet than the operator font would work, including `\Uplambda` from the `upgreek` package, the slanted `\mathnormal\Lambda` from plain LaTeX, loading any LGR font in math mode from `mathastext`, or the Greek alphabets in `isomath`.

### Change the Font Back

This is what Egreg’s answer does, by starting a new math group within the operator environment.  You might also use something like `\mbox{\(\Lambda\)}`.