# A symbol after horizontal line

Tags: line

I want to write this,

[image: equation]

```
$\begin{tabular}{11}
A &is true \\ 
B &is true \\ 
\hline A \wedge B  &is true 
\end{tabular}$
```

How do add the "^I" after `\hline`?

Comment: welcome to TEX - the syntax `multirow` will help since it combines two rows

Comment: also see this page -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61637/wedge-power-symbol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a LaTeX-based solution that employs a `\frac` expression.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for '\text' macro
\begin{document}
\[
\frac{\text{$A$ true} \quad \text{$B$ true}}{%
      \text{$A\wedge B$ true}}
\wedge I
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `ebproof` package that offers much more.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ebproof}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{prooftree}
\hypo{A \text{ true}}
\hypo{B \text{ true}}
\infer{2}[$\land I$]{A \land B \text{ true}}
\end{prooftree}
\]

\end{document}
```

The argument `{2}` refers to the fact that you have two `\hypo`  to typeset above the line.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

We can use `\over` primitive for fractions:

```
$$ {\ \hbox{A true}\quad\hbox{B true}\ \over\hbox{A $\wedge$ B}}\wedge \rm I $$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 3pt}
        
        \begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}
            
            A true                         & B true  &\Block{2-1}{$\wedge$ I}\\ \Hline
            \Block{1-2}{A $\wedge$ B true} &                                 \\
        \end{NiceTabular}
    
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]